# imageview not showing

Tags: java, android, image

I have this code to save the Uri of and image in shared preferences:

```
    // Save to settings
// imageReturnedIntent is the intent of selecting the image from the gallery
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("bannerImage2" , selectedImage.toString());
    editor.commit();
```

I have an imageview in the main activity, when the above code runs in the setting page, I go back to the main page the image is displayed correctly, but if I close the application and open it again, the image is not displayed even though that the Uri is loaded correctly.

I load the image in onResume() and I tried:

// IMAGE_LOGO is of type Uri
    imgLogo.setImageURI(IMAGE_LOGO);
Also tried to use Picasso library,

Also I tried to validate the image view again using

```
 imgLogo.invalidate();
```

The Uri returned is :

```
content://media/external/images/media/102124
```

Comment: Did you log for your `sharedPref` that carrying URI after restart application? - to be sure that this `sharedPref` is carrying vaild URI?

Comment: selectedImage is File ? Can you post your code so that i can understand what you're trying to do ?

Comment: What u mean? I watched the data returned when loading it and it is  correct

Comment: @HasanShouman What IMAGE_LOGO variable contains and it's type please

Comment: @HumzaMalik uri

Comment: onResume() try to retrive the String again from SharedPreferences.getString("bannerImage2",null);
then Uri my_img = Uri.parse(your_string_from_prefs); Then assin it to imageview

Comment: @HumzaMalik tried and did not work !.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160884/discussion-between-humza-malik-and-hasan-shouman).

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working you just need to get Read_External_Storage Permission as API level 23 requires this. To request permission on runtime you can referr to this document https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html.

Comment: I would like to thank Humza for his great help and opening a chat...Just saved my day..